# How can I Troubleshoot the Google Cloudstorage Client?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Given the sample code:

```
import cloudstorage
from django.shortcuts import render

def list_files(request):
  file_list = []
  try:
    bucket_name = my_bucket
    gcs_list_obj = cloudstorage.listbucket('/' + bucket_name, delimiter="/")
    for item in gcs_list_obj:
        file_list.append(item)

  except Exception, e:
    raise e

  return render(request, 'default.htm', {'file_list': file_list,
                                       'bucket_name': bucket_name})
```

The expectation would be to see a populated array of iterated objects from [cloudstorage.listbucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#listbucket)  Instead Django throws an `InternalError` with the message 
`5:`

What are the common steps for troubleshooting Storage buckets in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration, it seems there the issue was related to my project NOT [having a default bucket](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/QotaPSdq4ro).

Navigating to:
`https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/YOUR_PROJECT.appspot.com/`

Then uploading a few files / folders seems to have resolved the issue, and the sample code works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to add to file_list GCSFileStat objects (and are you handling it correctly in the template) or just the filenames.

If the latter than you can add item.filename instead.

Comment: Thanks - I'm familiar with the properties of the stat objects,  I was mostly shocked I wasn't getting objects back / seeing an exception raised.